# Trace map between Adele rings

Tags: number-theory

Let $L/K$ be a finite extension of number fields. Define the trace map
$$
\mathrm{Tr}_{L/K}: \mathbb{A}_{L}\to \mathbb{A}_{K}
$$
by
$$
\mathrm{Tr}_{L/K}(a)_{v} = \sum_{w|v} a_{w}
$$
where $v$ is a place of $K$ and $w$'s are places of $L$ lying over $v$. 
I want to know if this map is compatible with the usual trace map $L\to K$ via the isomorphism $\mathbb{A}_{L}\simeq \mathbb{A}_{K}\otimes_{K}L$ and $\mathbb{A}_{K}\otimes_{K}K$, and also I want to know if it induces a map $\mathbb{A}_{L}/L\to \mathbb{A}_{K}/K$.
I think I can control with finite places, but I always confuse with infinite places.